# Ubuntu Snap Service Configuration (for "webhook")

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

How do I set service configuration options for a snap.  Specifically this one:

https://snapcraft.io/webhook

I've tried:

```
$ sudo snap get webhook
error: snap "webhook" has no configuration

$ sudo snap set webhook foo=bar
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "webhook" snap (snap "webhook" has no "configure" hook)
```

The only config file I see is `/snap/webhook/5/meta/snap.yaml` and it appears the service has no configuration specified (it needs at least the `-hooks` option).  Also the snap config options seem to be `key=value` and the command takes `-option value`.

I want to set the options because if I run `snap start webhook` and then `snap logs webhook` I see:

```
2021-05-22T19:22:02Z webhook.webhook[2436]: aborting webhook execution since the -verbose flag is set to false.
2021-05-22T19:22:02Z webhook.webhook[2436]: If, for some reason, you want webhook to start without the hooks, either use -verbose flag, or -nopanic
2021-05-22T19:22:02Z systemd[1]: snap.webhook.webhook.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2021-05-22T19:22:02Z systemd[1]: snap.webhook.webhook.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application webhook.webhook.
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z webhook.webhook[2647]: [webhook] 2021/05/22 19:34:40 couldn't load any hooks from file!
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z webhook.webhook[2647]: aborting webhook execution since the -verbose flag is set to false.
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z webhook.webhook[2647]: If, for some reason, you want webhook to start without the hooks, either use -verbose flag, or -nopanic
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z systemd[1]: snap.webhook.webhook.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2021-05-22T19:34:40Z systemd[1]: snap.webhook.webhook.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic but any help would be appreciated.